# Create special vectors with R commands

Tags: r

I want to create the vectors with R commands: 
(4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, ..., 4, 6, 3, 4, 6) where there are 10 occurrences of 4, 10 occurrences of 6, and 9 occurrences of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rep` and its `length.out` argument

```
x <- rep(c(4, 6, 3), length.out = 29)
x
#[1] 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6 3 4 6
```

Count the occurrences of each element

```
table(x)
#x
# 3  4  6 
# 9 10 10
```

You could also use `rep_len` as suggested by @snoram

```
rep_len(c(4, 6, 3), 29)
```

Comment: or slightly more succinct: `rep_len(c(4, 6, 3), 29)`

Comment: thanks you, it work!